# Iterate over a number of divs and extract info into an array?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a page with a couple divs like this

```
<div class="market_listing_row" id="12345">
 ...
 <div class="priceblock">
  <span class="price">0,0</span>
 </div>
</div>
```

I want to make an array of JS objects for each of them:

```
[{ id: '12345', price: '0,0'}]
```

How do I iterate over these divs? I tried to do it with jQuery and raw JS, but failed.

EDIT:
Apparently CasperJS and jQuery together cause a mess, probably because of the 'this'. Either way I found a way to deal with the problem using casper module methods:

```
 var price = this.fetchText('div.market_listing_row .price').split('\n');
var id = this.getElementsAttribute('div.market_listing_row', 'id');
```

This creates two arrays: for prices and ids.

Comment: 1 thing, [{ id: 12345, price: 0,0}] is invalid and will need to be made a string - [{ id: 12345, price: "0,0"}]

Answer (score 2):

I'd suggest:

```
var objArray = $('.market_listing_row').map(function () {
    return {
        'id': this.id,
        'price': $(this).find('.price').text()
    };
}).get();
```

[JS Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/dqvf3/).

References:

- [`find()`](http://api.jquery.com/find/).
- [`get()`](http://api.jquery.com/get/).
- [`map()`](http://api.jquery.com/map/).

Comment: Why do you use 'this.' with id, but '$(this).' when navigating the children?

Comment: @Euphe if you wrap this with $() it will become a Jquery object, so that you can make use of Jquery functions with that.

Comment: I tried your solution and when I do this.echo(array.length) it outputs 0

Comment: Really? Then show a live demo (update my own demo, click on 'save' and share the link with us, to show what you're doing, and how) and I'll try and explain how to make work, or what you're doing wrong.

Answer (score 1):

Try,

```
xResult = [];

$('.market_listing_row').each(function(){

   var xJson = {};
   xJson.id = $(this).attr('id');
   xJson.price = $(this).find('.price').text();

   xResult[xResult.length] = xJson;

});
```

Answer (score 1):

[JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/wrxsti85/6Leec/)

I made a very basic example on fiddle using the following code.

```
var arr = [];
$('.market_listing_row').each(function(){
    id = $(this).attr('id');
    price = $(this).find('.price').text();
    arr.push({id: id, price: price});
});
```

Let me know if you have any questions. Hope this helps!

Answer (score 1):

H i, throwing the native ( raw js ) version into the mix. http://jsfiddle.net/sD67h/1/

With the help of:

```
function $class(str,_scope) {
  if(!_scope) { _scope=document; }
    var elems = _scope.getElementsByTagName('*'), elArray =[];
    var len=elems.length;
      for (var cnt = 0; cnt < len; ++cnt) {
        if((' ' + elems[cnt].className + ' ').indexOf(' ' + str + ' ') > -1) {
             elArray.push(elems[cnt]);
        }
      }
      return elArray;
  }
```

To suit your markup setup, can be used like this:

```
function getPriceObjects() {
    var marketrows = $class("market_listing_row"), marketArray=[];
    for (var i = 0, len=marketrows.length; i < len; ++i) {
     var id = marketrows[i].getAttribute("id");
     var price = $class("price",marketrows[i])[0].innerHTML;
        marketArray.push({ id: id, price: price});
     }
    return marketArray;
}

var marketPriceArray = getPriceObjects();
```

Comment: Hi Euphe, did you include the top function called $class ? - http://jsfiddle.net/sD67h/1/